# remove list from another list in dart

Tags: dart

I have two lists, `lst1` and `lst2`. I want to perform `lst1 - lst2`, which returns all elements of `lst1` not in `lst2`.

```
var lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t3" , "t4"];
var lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];
//output: ["t1" , "t3"]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Convert to sets and take the difference, then convert back to a list (with the caveat that neither duplicates nor the ordering of elements will be preserved):

```
void main() {
  var lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t3" , "t4"];
  var lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];
  var set1 = Set.from(lst1);
  var set2 = Set.from(lst2);
  print(List.from(set1.difference(set2)));
}
```

Output

```
[t1, t3]
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0ksKvn/vyw/M0UhNzEzT0NToZpLQaEssUghp7jEUMFWIVqpxFBJQUdBqcQIQhlDKBOlWGuESiOISiOYHJgyRSgpTgUbFpxaopdWlJ@rATJcE0nSCE3SCCxZUJSZV6Lhk1kMlQCZopeSmZaWWpSal5wK4htpagKV1v7/DwA)

Comment: I assume per the nature of sets that maintaining order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 8):

The method using sets suggested by [Ray Toal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59423432/10066711) is probably the fastest, but if your first list contains duplicates that you want to keep, sets will completely destroy them.

Instead, you could use a simple list filtering method.

```dart
void main() {
  var lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t2", "t3" , "t3", "t4"];  // introduce duplicates
  var lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];

  var set1 = Set.from(lst1);
  var set2 = Set.from(lst2);
  print(List.from(set1.difference(set2)));
  // Output : [t1, t3]

  var filtered_lst = List.from(lst1.where(
    (value) => !lst2.contains(value)));
  print(filtered_lst);
  // Output: [t1, t3, t3]
}
```

If there is duplicates in both lists and you actually want to subtract list item per item, you could use the `remove` method (*warning*: this will actually remove items from your first list, so you might need to create a copy first).

```dart
void main() {
  var lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t2", "t3" , "t3", "t4"];  // introduce duplicates
  var lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];

  for (var elem in lst2) {
    lst1.remove(elem);
  }
  print(lst1);
  // Output : [t1, t2, t3, t3]
  // only one occurrence of "t2" was removed.
}
```

Comment: Oooh right, your answer is better if duplicates need to be kept and order preserved.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in a non-destructive way and preserve the order, you can create an Iterable extension for this.

```
void main() {
  final lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t3" , "t4"];
  final lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];
  final diff = lst1.whereNotIn(lst2).toList();
  print(diff);
}

extension WhereNotInExt<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<T> whereNotIn(Iterable<T> reject) {
    final rejectSet = reject.toSet();
    return where((el) => !rejectSet.contains(el));
  }
}
```

Try it out here: https://dartpad.dev/88c5c949b6ac8c2d0812e15ce10e40ce?null_safety=true

Some benefits to this approach:

- Doesn't mutate the original list
- Preserves the original order
- Works on Iterable too
- It uses a set to keep track of the elements to reject, so it doesn't slow down a lot if both lists are large

Answer (score 2):

```
var lst1 = ["t1" , "t2" , "t3" , "t4"];
var lst2 = ["t2" , "t4" , "t5"];

lst1 = lst1.removeWhere((item) => lst2!.contains(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

solutions with sets are quite working.
however, it is worth remembering that if you have a set of objects, then you need overloading operator == and hashCode in these objects.